# How to expand given path in SWT/Tree and/or JFace/TreeViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, treeview, swt, jface

I wrote very big an lazy tree model and can't expand it programmatically by given path

Below is entire `ViewPart` code.

Tree works fine interactively, i.e. I can open all levels up to 10. But I can't do that programmatically.

I wrote custom `ViewElementComparer` to compare elements.

```
package try_13_expandtreeview;

import org.eclipse.jface.action.Action;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IElementComparer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreePath;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.ISharedImages;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class View extends ViewPart {

    public static final String ID = "Try_13_ExpandTreeView.view";

    private TreeViewer viewer;

    private Action action1;

    /**
     * Each model element is a "triad", i.e. new Object[3]
     * 
     * First element of a triad is a parent element
     * 
     * Second number is a level, numbered from leafs to root
     * 
     * Third number is numeric value (content) of an element
     * 
     * @author dims
     *
     */
    class ViewContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {
        public void inputChanged(Viewer v, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        }

        public void dispose() {
        }

        public Object[] getElements(Object parent) {
            return getChildren(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] getChildren(Object parent) {
            Object[] triade = (Object[]) parent;
            if( ((int)triade[1]) > 0 ) {
                Object[] children = new Object[10];
                Object[] child;
                for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
                    child = new Object[3];
                    child[0] = parent;
                    child[1] = ((int)triade[1])-1;
                    child[2] = i;
                    children[i] = child;
                }
                return children;
            }
            else {
                return new Object[0];
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object getParent(Object element) {
            Object[] triade = (Object[]) element;
            return triade[0];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
            Object[] triade = (Object[]) element;
            return ((int)triade[1]) > 0;
        }
    }

    class ViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            Object[] triade = (Object[]) element;
            return ((Integer)triade[2]).toString();
        }
    }

    class ViewElementComparer implements IElementComparer {

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
            Object[] triade_a = (Object[]) a;
            Object[] triade_b = (Object[]) b;
            return ((int)triade_a[2]) == ((int)triade_b[2]); 
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode(Object element) {
            Object[] triade = (Object[]) element;
            return ((int)triade[2]);
        }

    }

    /**
     * This is a callback that will allow us to create the viewer and initialize
     * it.
     */
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        viewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
                | SWT.V_SCROLL);

        viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
        viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
        viewer.setComparer(new ViewElementComparer());

        viewer.setInput(new Object[] {null, 10, 0});

        action1 = new Action() {
            public void run() {


                TreePath[] treePaths = {
                        new TreePath(new Object[] {
                                new Object[] {null, 0, 2},
                                new Object[] {null, 0, 7},
                                new Object[] {null, 0, 4}
                        })
                };

                // viewer.setExpandedTreePaths(treePaths); // does not work 
                viewer.expandToLevel(treePaths[0], TreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);





                //viewer.setExpandedElements(new Object[] { viewer.getTree().getItems()[3].getData()});
            }
        };
        action1.setText("Action 1");
        action1.setToolTipText("Action 1 tooltip");
        action1.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
            getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK));

        getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager().add(action1);
    }

    /**
     * Passing the focus request to the viewer's control.
     */
    public void setFocus() {
        viewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TreePath` parameter to these calls is just an array of objects from the object model (as provided by your content provider). The array starts at the top level object in the tree (one of the objects returned by the content provider `getElements` call). The second entry in the array is the child of the top level elements, and so on with each child you want to expand.

The `getTreePathFromItem` code you show is starting with the 'leaf' of the tree it wants to expand and working back up through the item parents to the top of the tree. Since the tree path needs to be top to bottom the list it builds is reversed.

Calling `TreeViewer.setUseHashlookup(true)` helps the tree viewer when it is looking up these objects.

Update: `internalGetWidgetToSelect` operation with a `TreePath` input, after checking for an empty path we have the call:

```
Widget[] candidates = findItems(treePath.getLastSegment());
```

It appears from the comments that it is possible to have multiple tree items for the same model object - I'm not sure when this is used but I don't think it is usual. If you do have multiple tree items then the `TreePath` is ambiguous so the code looks at the parent tree path for each item in turn to find a match.

So in the normal case with only one leaf item for a model object this is probably faster than starting at the root of the tree path and finding each child since there is less search for tree items matching model objects.

Comment: Okay I understood the approach correctness, but don't understand it's effectiveness. Suppose I have unambiguous paths, but has numerous identical leafs on the ends. Why start searching from the end? This will give numerous candidates! Why don't searching from root to leafs?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Library code looks strange; as if it is browsing not my tree hierarchy but visual controls hierarchy. At some moment `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.findItems(Object)` just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just do expandAll on the viewer and then examine the result of getExpandedTreePaths.

If you have the following tree...

```
N1
  N1B
    N1C
N2
N3
..
```

...and you want to make N1C visible, you have to do setExpandedPaths with an array of three TreePath's

```
tp1 = new TreePath({N1});
tp2 = new TreePath({N1, N1B});
tp3 = new TreePath({N1, N1B, N1C});
// viewer.expandAll()
viewer.setExpandedTreePaths({tp1, tp2, tp3});
```